# Jquery message only on first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem: when clicking on edit buttom, the message of the successful/error alert is displayed only on the first row even if i click on the second.
This is the js

```
var ROUTE = new function () {
    var oGlobal = this;
    this.sSaveUrl = '';

    this.setSaveUrl = function (_sUrl) {
        this.sSaveUrl = _sUrl;
    }

    this.setEventSubmit = function () {
        $('[id^="route_update"]').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                var oData = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').serializeArray();
                var oRow = $(this).closest('tr');

                console.log(oData);

                oReq = $.post(oGlobal.sSaveUrl, oData, function (data) {
                    if (data['valid'] != "true") {
                        //console.log('error');
                        //Fade in
                        oRow.closest('#comment').html('Error').css('display', 'block').fadeIn(1000);
                        //Fade out
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#comment').html('').fadeOut(1000);
                        }, 1500);
                        //fade in
                        $('#comment')
                    } else {
                        //console.log('success');
                        //Fade in
                        $('#comment').html('Insert Success').fadeIn(1000);
                        //Fade out
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#comment').html('').fadeOut(1000);
                        }, 1500);
                        //fade in
                        $('#comment')
                    }
                    return false;
                }, 'json');

                return false;
            });
        });
    }

    this.init = function () {
        this.setEventSubmit();
    }
}
```

What do I wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the relevant code inline.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Dunno what I wrong so I prefered to show all the cose

Comment: @user3754474 The point of StackOverflow is as a long term resource.  Links may well be dead in future.  It's much better to add your code inline.  People are also far more likely to actually try to answer it if they don't have to go off to an external site to see the problem.